# Visual Studio WebSetup Installer, install to multiple web sites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, web-setup-project

I want to make an installer that reads the directories where it should install from registry, and with this data collected show a window with these directories, each one with a checkbox for selecting if they want to install in that directory and perform the installation in these directories.

If it is not possible with visual studio websetup project, anyone knows another installer that can do that? or another way of doing this mostly automatically

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have made a winforms app that fits my needs

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in VS, but [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) can be used to get what you need. You have access to a Dialogs Editor, Search page and everything else that you need. During the trial period you can access all of these features, just make sure you have Enterprise set as projects type to be able to use the desired features.

Comment: Thanks for this great tool, but finally I have made an app that does the work